# On clicking an element get child hidden input field's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code when I click on anchor tag with class `des_searchDate`
I want to get the value of immediate following input field value.

I tried following

```
<html>
    <div class="searched_date">
        <a href="#" class="des_searchDate">
            04-15-2014
            <input type="hidden" value="2014-04-15" name="searched-date">
        </a><br>
        <a href="#" class="des_searchDate">
            04-09-2014
            <input type="hidden" value="2014-04-09" name="searched-date">
        </a><br>
        <a href="#" class="des_searchDate">
            04-23-2014
            <input type="hidden" value="2014-04-23" name="searched-date">
        </a><br>
     </div>
 </html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).on('click', ".des_searchDate", function(){

    var decDate = jQuery(this).next().find('input').val();

alert(decDate);
});

</script>
```

But I am getting undefined in alert. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Muk Do you want value of input inside anchor?

Comment: I think `<input>` inside `<a>` is not valid HTML markup, isn't it?

Comment: @Felix I know but I have some requirement like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".des_searchDate", function(){
var decDate = jQuery(this).find('input').val();
alert(decDate);
});
```

[<kbd>demo fiddle</kbd>](http://fiddle.jshell.net/upP9D/1/)

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".des_searchDate", function(){
    var decDate = jQuery(this).find('input').val();
    alert(decDate);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yT777/

Comment: Ah, this is most likley correct. I was assuming OP wanted next element but i didn't read the the title. **+1**

Comment: @Anton I'm usually guilty of doing that too so it makes a change for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value of input inside the clicked anchor:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".des_searchDate", function(){
var decDate = jQuery(this).find('input').val();
alert(decDate);
});
```

Or if you need the value of next input following the clicked anchor:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".des_searchDate", function(){
var decDate = jQuery(this).nextAll('input:first').val();
alert(decDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.des_searchDate').click( function(){
    var decDate = $(this).find('input').val();
    alert(decDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure javascript, no need for jQuery:

[Pure JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSsv6/)

```
var sd = document.getElementsByClassName("des_searchDate");

for (i = 0;i<sd.length;i++){
  var s = sd[i];
  s.onclick = function(){
    var input = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    alert(input.value);
  }
}
```